# Php run MySqli query

Tags: php, mysqli

This might be a stupid question but i can't seem to understand this.
If i run a MySqli query like this

```
$variable = mysqli_query($con, "Some Database Query Here");
```

After the query is executed, does the variable stores a bool result like TRUE if the query was executed correctly or FALSE if not? or does it store data returned by the query?

Comment: check this out http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: It returns TRUE if the query was executed succesfuly, or FALSE if an error occured. In specific instances it will return a result object. As per [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: Note: please do NOT use w3schools, the site has proven to show outdated documentation and give very bad (often insecure) advice. For PHP *always* use [the official PHP manual](http://www.php.net/) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [manual](http://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Comment: I should really start reading that manual instead of just looking at the examples! Thanks i understand now.

Answer (score 1):

As you can check in documentatio [here](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) it will return TRUE if the query was executed correctly and FALSE if it has errors.

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.